# Tag excerpt inconsistently displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Here is the state of the tag [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) as I wrote this question:

[image: usage tag]

On the the tags page, [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) appears with the first seven words of the excerpt truncated, rendering it mostly useless:

[image: truncated on tags page]

Furthermore, the tag popup shows an outdated version of the except, containing the redundant "Questions concerning", which I removed yesterday:

[image: outdated popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary invalid popup was a caching bug (fixed - to be deployed later)

Currently this is the regex that we use for shortening:

```
       @"^.{0,40}?
            (
            (this\stag\s(is)?\s?)  # this tag .. this tag is|about ...
            |
            (used\sto\s)           # this tag is used to ...
            |
            (the\s[^\s]+\stag\s)   # the {foo} tag ...
            |
            (the\stag\s[^\s]+)     # the tag {foo} ...
            |
            (\s(is|are)\s)         # blah blah blah is|are ...
            )"
```

`are` is hitting in the first 40 chars, so its dropping stuff before it. Can you rephrase it so this filter does not hit?

Comment: Thanks! I changed the wording of that tag; however, that last clause in the regex seems to me like too big a dragnet that will mangle more than just this one tag.